# OpenGL faded square

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to achieve a fade effect, where the corners of a square have different alphas. I'm doing this:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glColor4d(r, g, b, alphaTopLeft);
glVertex2d(x, y);
glColor4d(r, g, b, alphaTopRight);
glVertex2d(x + width, y);
glColor4d(r, g, b, alphaBottomRight);
glVertex2d(x + width, y + height);
glColor4d(r, g, b, alphaBottomLeft);
glVertex2d(x, y + height);

glEnd();
```

With the values alphaTopLeft = 0, alphaTopRight = 0, alphaBottomRight = 1, alphaBottomLeft = 1, but it produces a solid shape (all corners alpha 1), why?

Comment: Have you enabled `GL_BLEND`? Try adding this before you render: `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); glEnable( GL_BLEND ); glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you enabled `GL_BLEND`? Try adding this before you render:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 
glEnable( GL_BLEND );
```

Comment: Surely glClearColor has nothing to do with blending here?

Comment: @immibis Sure! I removed it.